# how to create an empty buffer in elscreen?

Tags: emacs

When I open a new tab in elscreen, it will open the scratch buffer. So if I copy something to a scratch buffer, and then open a new tab, that tab will show the same thing in the previous tab. But actually I need an empty buffer. HOw to do that?

Comment: Which version of El-screen are you using? There are a few variants with the same / similar name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple elisp function that calls `elscreen-create` and opens a new dummy buffer:

```
(defun my-elscreen-create ()
     (interactive)
     (elscreen-create)
     (switch-to-buffer (concat "test-" (number-to-string (elscreen-get-number-of-screens)))  ;; make it unique
     ))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the version of elscreen [here](http://www.morishima.net/~naoto/elscreen-en/?lang=en) or [here](https://github.com/shosti/elscreen) then this might help you (There is a elscreen-create-hook but further buffer manipulation takes place after it's called, so I've been using this advice for the last year or so to do something similar):

```
(defadvice elscreen-create (after new-blank-buffer)
(let* ((new-buffer (generate-new-buffer "blank"))
       (blank-buffer-name (buffer-name new-buffer)))
   (switch-to-buffer blank-buffer-name)))

(ad-activate 'elscreen-create)
```